# Simple Integer C# Unity i=i+1 not adding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, integer

so i'm trying to do a little game on unity . And i did a script , when you press left click on an object , it open a canvas and another one and then it add +1 to i , like that when i found every object . (so when i=3) it shows the end screen. But when i go in game mode , when i press left click it doesnt add the number , like every object have his same i , but i dont understand they have the same function no ?

And sometimes 2 of 3 works, i dont know if thats clear to understand.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
    
public class ActionObjet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image image1;
    public Image image2;
    public Image image3;
    public int i = 0;
    
    void Start()
    {
        image1.enabled = false;
        image2.enabled = false;
        image3.enabled = false;
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            if (image1.enabled == true)
            {
                i = i + 1;
                print(i);
                image2.enabled = !image2.enabled;
                image1.enabled = !image1.enabled;
                FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("bruit_recuperer_objet");                    
            }
        }
    }
    
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (image1.enabled == false) 
        {
            image1.enabled = !image1.enabled;
        }
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOSJH.png

Comment: Don't post images of code. We can't copy code from an image to run it or modify it. Post the code as text, formatted as code.

Comment: A lot of times GUI libraries instantiate new object every time, or let them expire if not used within a certain time.  Could be that every click is getting a brand new i, initialized to 0.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution , I'm a bit sad that I wasted 5 hours just for that but yea..

I just changed the

```
public int i=0
```

into

```
static int i=0;
```

This is because each gameObject with this script has its own instance of all the variables. A static variable's value is universal to all instances of the same class so any one of them can update it for all of them when marked static.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).